# Calculating the number of days in a specific year within a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Sample data:

[image: Sample data]

Hi, I am struggling with finding the right Excel formula to return the number of days in a specific year within a date range.
There was a similar post back in 2010 but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Which post in 2010, please provide the link. Why did it not work for you? What was wrong? What else have you tried and what was wrong with those attempts?

Comment: You've obviously supplied a screenshot of your attempted non-working formula in action. While that is also useful, it is *essential* to post an **accurate** mock-up of what the actual result should look like. Plus, also adding your non-working formula shows us you have made a genuine attempt at the problem. It also allows us to help you improve your Excel skills by pointing out the issues with it. Please don't add the new info in a comment, but [edit your question](//superuser.com/posts/1333847/edit) and add it there. The same goes for what Tom said.

Comment: I've voted this to Reopen since [Similar Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1396353/calculate-the-number-of-days-per-year-between-two-different-dates-excel) has been asked and the formula suggested specially the `SUMPRODUCT` is quite complicated,, but here all suggested formula are as simple !!

Comment: With all due respect to their authors, answers should not have been posted to this question which doesn’t show expected output or any attempt to solve the problem. The fact that this bad question has received good answers is not a valid justification to reopen it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm seeing a simple solution that doesn't require VBA (this is a long answer for a simple solution because it includes variations to cover several things that are ambiguous in the question).

[image]

Note that this answer contains multiple versions of the formula for different use cases.  The formula shown in the image is just one, and reflects "duration" rather than day count, as shown in the question's example.

**"Number of Days" definition**

There are several ways to interpret this.  If something starts in the middle of today and ends in the middle of tomorrow, you might consider that a duration of one day.  If you are interested in the calendar days over which it occurred, you would consider that two days.  I'll show both cases and you can apply the one relevant to you.

**Start and Finish are just dates vs. date/times**

If the range Start and Finish are just dates, the range will be stored in units of whole days, so you can use simple arithmetic to calculate durations.  If they are actually stored as date/times and you are just displaying the date portion, the hidden time information can cause unexpected rounding errors.  I'll show a solution for both cases.

**Solutions: Duration Basis**

So the task is determining whether any portion of the range falls within the given year, then calculating the duration of the part that does.  This formula uses the year column headers, so it requires one year column beyond the last finish date.

If the range Start and Finish are **just dates** and the objective is "duration", the formula in D2 (drag to fill the matrix):

```
=IF(OR($A2>=E$1,$B2<D$1),0,MIN($B2,E$1)-MAX($A2,D$1))
```

If the range Start and Finish contain **date/time** information and the objective is "duration", the formula in D2:

```
=IF(OR($A2>=E$1,$B2<D$1),0,DATEDIF(MAX($A2,D$1),MIN($B2,E$1),"D"))
```

The built-in DATEDIF function gives you the difference between dates (ignoring time information), and you can specify the units displayed.

**Explanation**

In these two formulas, the IF test checks whether the Start date is after the end of the current year or the Finish date is before the current year.  If so, it fills a zero.

Otherwise, it calculates the date difference.  It uses the later of the year start (continuation of the range from a prior year), or the range start (begins sometime during the year), and the earlier of the range end (ends during the year), or the start of the next year (range continues into the next year).

**Solution: Day Count Basis**

If your objective is to count every day in the range as a full day, we need to add one day to the last year's entry for the range.  A simple way to do that is with the Boolean value (true=1, false=0) of a test for whether the Finish year equals the "current" year: `(YEAR($B2)=YEAR(D$1))`, which can be added to either of the above formulas.  Using the first formula for example:

```
=IF(OR($A2>=E$1,$B2<D$1),0,MIN($B2,E$1)-MAX($A2,D$1)+(YEAR($B2)=YEAR(D$1)))
```

Comment: Since you are subtracting Days `DATEDIF` is superfluous.  To check for the last year, instead of your `IF` just use `... + (YEAR($B2)=YEAR(D$1))`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, good points.  I'll incorporate them.

Comment: Great solution. You know, my first attempt at a solution started off using `MIN()` and `MAX()`. I cannot remember why I abandoned that approach for the one I ended up using. Must have been very late last night ;-)

Comment: Hi fixer1234, I am now successfully using your formula. Thanks so much for sharing your expertise - solution and approach. I am humbled by the detailed responses from yourself and other posters. Thanks so much.

Comment: @fixer1234,, it's better also,, [Similar issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1396353/calculate-the-number-of-days-per-year-between-two-different-dates-excel) has been raised and the SUMPRODUCT formula seems quite complicated !

Answer (score 3):

The formula solution is pretty straightforward:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `D2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down into `D2:K4`:

```dart
=
IF(AND(YEAR(D$1)=YEAR($A2),YEAR(D$1)=YEAR($B2)),$B2-$A2+1,
IF(YEAR(D$1)=YEAR($A2),EDATE(D$1,12)-$A2,
IF(YEAR(D$1)=YEAR($B2),$B2-D$1+1,
IF(AND(YEAR(D$1)>YEAR($A2),YEAR(D$1)<YEAR($B2)),EDATE(D$1,12)-D$1,
0
))))
```

The key to solving the problem is to split it into five separate cases:

1. The Start and Finish years match the year in question
2. Only the Start year matches
3. Only the Finish year matches
4. The year in question falls in between the Start and Finish years
5. The year in question falls outside the Start and Finish years

---

EDIT:

Seeing fixer1234's solution made wonder why I gave up my initial idea of using `MIN()` & `MAX()` to solve the problem - apparently for no good reason.

Here's the solution I should have originally proposed:

```dart
=(EDATE(D$1,12)>=$A2)*(D$1<=$B2)*(MIN($B2,EDATE(D$1,12))-MAX($A2,D$1)+(YEAR(D$1)=YEAR($B2)))
```

Comment: @fixer1234 Yeah. Since the OP's post is full of errors, I figured that it would be best to be inclusive of both end points. Otherwise, which day do you leave out, first, last or both? The duration column implies only one is left out. The values in `I4`, `F2`, and `F3` imply that the last day is counted The values in column `E` are so far off that nothing can be gleaned about the first day. Technically the data supplied only allows the first day to be omitted. Also, thanks for the heads up. To compound the OP's errors *my* formula had one too. All fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function DateCounter(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, yeer As Long) As Long
    Dim d As Date
    DateCounter = 0

    For d = StartDate To EndDate
        If Year(d) = yeer Then DateCounter = DateCounter + 1
    Next d
End Function
```

The first argument is the start date, the second argument is the end date and the third argument is the year.  For example:

[image]

So the total number of days between *(and including)* 20 November 2016 and 15 March 2017 that fall in year 2016 is 42.
User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=myfunction(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: It's the simple & non complicated,,, +1  ☺