# Calculate the number of days per year between two different dates Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel data sheet which contains about 200 rows, in each row, there is a Start date and End date. I need to calculate the difference between the dates but per year. 
suppose the start date is 3/3/2017 and the End date is 3/2/2019, I need to calculate the number of days in 2017, 2018 and 2019 between both dates.

Comment: You want the total number of days between the start and end or 3 different numbers representing each year in the range?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This formula should work up to 25 November 4770, by which time Excel may have been superseded by something else.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(ROW(INDIRECT(StartDt &":"&endDt)))=C$1))
```

where C1 contains the year in question.

For example:

[image]

However, you write you want to know the "difference between the dates". That phraseology usually indicates that you don't want to count the first date. The formula counts all of the dates.

If you really want the "difference" and not the number of days from Start to End, then add one to the start date in the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(ROW(INDIRECT(StartDt+1 &":"&endDt)))=C$1))
```

**Edit:** *(provoked by @fixer1234)* To understand how this is working, you need to understand that

- dates are stored in Excel as serial numbers with, usually, `1-jan-1900` equal to **1**.
- `ROW(INDIRECT(n:m))` is a way of returning an array of numbers equal to the row numbers represented by `n` and `m`
- The `YEAR` function then returns the the equivalent year from each of those values, with we compare with the year at the top of the relevant column, generating an array of `TRUE;FALSE`.
- Since, in Excel, `--TRUE` = `1`, `SUMPRODUCT` will effectively return the `SUM` of all the dates that are in the year at the top of the column.
- The date limitation I mentioned is because the are only `2^20` rows in Excel. It could be overcome by applying an offset to the dates within the `ROW(INDIRECT(…` construct, and then adding that back after, if the dates involved are later than 11/25/4770.

Comment: Clever, but suggest changing the "named ranges" to explicit ranges so that this solution works in spreadsheet apps other than Excel.  e.g., C2: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(ROW(INDIRECT($A2&":"&$B2)))=C$1))`.  That was the only way I could get this to work in LO Calc.  It would also be helpful to add a few sentences to explain how it works using imaginary rows.

Comment: I **agree** that an explanation of the algorithm might be useful, although I think readers are better served, with non-complex algorithms, by making the effort to figure it out themselves.  I **disagree** about avoiding "named ranges". I feel they lend clarity to the formula and make future maintenance easier. I do include caveats if there are applications listed in the tags in which the formula might not work, or with which I am not familiar. However, that was not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, let's say for the example that you want the number of days in 2019 between two dates.
If starting date = 30/12/2019 and end date = 03/01/2021 the formula should return the number 2. (or 1 depending how you want to count).

To do that, try the following :

= Max(31/12/2018,Min(end date,31/12/2019)) - Min(31/12/2019,Max(starting date,31/122018))

where instead of the date you will have a cell reference where the dates (31/12/2018 and 2019) are entered.

The only caveat I have found with this formula is that you have to make sure that end date is greater or equal to start date. Logically that should always be the case, except if one date is missing or entered wrong.

Hope this helps.

Cheers